OpenAI HTTP 400 JSON Parsing Error for Certain PDFS and via Mobile
I'm receiving the attached error when trying to pass text extracted from a PDF to OpenAI. I receive this Chat Completions error. This happens only with certain PDFs when I'm working on my app from the app, but this happens all the time from my mobile device. This also happened with gpt-3.5-turbo. Here is how my OpenAI API is set up. Any help would be much appreciated!
{
"model": "gpt-4o",
"messages": [
{
"role": "system",
"content": "You are a helpful assistant. You can understand and respond based on the content provided from a document."
},
{
"role": "system",
"content": "Document Content: <extracted_text_from_pdf>"
},
{
"role": "user",
"content": ""
}
]
}
I'd expect the chat completion would return successful and not receive this error.
